# Maven Tycho: find out where transitive dependencies are coming from

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management, tycho

I have a Maven project setup with [Tycho](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho). Is there a way of finding out where a transitive dependency is coming from? (e.g., by showing a dependency tree)

---

### Background

I am trying to address vulnerabilities that were found in some of our dependencies by running

```
mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check -DfailBuildOnCVSS=7
```

Most of the dependencies that show up are actually transitive dependencies, so they are actually not directly present in our project. To find out where they are coming from, I tried running `mvn dependency:tree`, but due to the way Tycho works, all dependencies that Tycho fetches show up as direct dependencies, so I've no idea where they're coming from.

Is there a way of finding out where a transative dependency is coming from? E.g., a Tycho-way of running `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: Tycho questions are probably better asked on [tycho discussions](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions), there are more tycho users there.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, I asked it here: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions/1647

Comment: Keep in mind that such a tree shows only one solution based of what is available, but in the OSGi/Eclipse world dependencies are specified by version ranges based on semantic versioning and dependencies are also resolved at runtime. For example, if you install an Eclipse plugin/feature, a faulty required bundle might not be updated when another plugin/feature requires the older version as long as it is in the version range of what the installed plugin/feature requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tycho 3.0.0, a new mojo, `tycho-p2-plugin:dependency-tree` has been added. It has been announced here: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#new-tycho-p2-plugindependency-tree-mojo